# How to use both Jquery Terminal as Quake like Console and RPC from examples

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-terminal

I'm using the JQuery Terminal here: http://terminal.jcubic.pl/

I am trying to create a console style terminal (Quake-like console) as outlined in example 2 from this page: http://terminal.jcubic.pl/examples.php

I also want it to call back to an RPC service, as listed in example 1.

Perhaps someone with more JQuery experience than I can tell me if they believe its possible to do this? I'm trying to do both together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply put string as first argument to tilda example plugin or you can call your RPC inside eval function.

```
 $('#tilda').tilda('rpc-service.php', { <OPTIONS> });
```

first argument to tilda is passed to terminal executed inside so you can do the same for tilda as for the terminal.